# Is there a more idiomatic way to simplify the results of a leftJoin?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm working on a Scala 2.12.x and Slick 3.3.0 project and I have a recurrent use-case of handling the results of a `joinLeft` operation.

The left join gives me this as result: `Future[Seq[(A, Option[B])]]` where `A` is the master-table's type and `B` is the detail-table's type. In other words, I get a sequence of the master element `A` repeated for as many times there were left joined instances of `B`. I'd like to simplify this complex repeating type to a more manageable result type `Future[Option[(A, Seq[B])]]`. To this end I created the following function:

```
implicit def simplify[A, B](x: Future[Seq[(A, Option[B])]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[(A, Seq[B])]] = {
  x.map {
    case results => {
      val seq: Seq[B] = results.map(_._2).map {
        case Some(b) => Some(b)
        case _ => None.asInstanceOf[Option[B]]
      }.filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(_.get) match {
        case seq if (seq.nonEmpty) => seq
        case _ => Seq()
      }

      results.headOption.map {
        case (a, _) => (a, seq)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it looks a bit too complex AND it doesn't account for the fact that there could be more than one `A` instance e.g.

```
a1 b11
a1 b12
a1 b13
a2 b21
a2 b22
```

Note that in this case my function would give an incorrect result: `Future[Some((a1, Seq(b11, b12, b13, b21, b22)))]` , the correct result would be `Future[Some((a1, Seq(b11, b12, b13)))]`

How can I make it simpler and correct?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `def simplify[A, B](x: Future[Seq[(A, Option[B])]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[(A, Seq[B])]] = x.map(_.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2)).toSeq)`

Comment: Wow nice one liner ... can you make it an answer and explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine the A values with all the corrensponding B values that are defined, you can use `groupBy(_._1)` to group by the first element of the tuple and then flatten the B options by applying `mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2))`

```
def simplify[A, B](x: Future[Seq[(A, Option[B])]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
   : Future[Map[A, Seq[B]]] =
  x.map(_.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2)))
```

I changed the return type to `Future[Map[A, Seq[B]]]` to allow different A values